# Custom Form in WordPress w/ if-statement

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, if-statement

So I'm trying to get a custom form working in WordPress. I have a Insert PHP plugin installed so `[insert_php]` is the same as `<?php` in my following script.

Basically no plugin I've seen has what I need so I created my own with PHP and when the if-statement on line 64 is supposed to run, it starts again and I have absolutely no idea why.

I have set the session variables and all my forms are using the POST method if that makes any difference.

The script:

```
<div id="mcoc_form">
[insert_php]

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['name']   = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['stars3'] = $_POST['tstar'];
    $_SESSION['stars4'] = $_POST['fstar'];
    $_SESSION['points3']= $_POST['tpoints'];
    $_SESSION['rank3']  = $_POST['trank'];
    $_SESSION['points4']= $_POST['fpoints'];
    $_SESSION['rank4']  = $_POST['frank'];

    $_SESSION['name_set']   = isset($_SESSION['name']);
    $_SESSION['stars3_set'] = isset($_SESSION['stars3']);
    $_SESSION['stars4_set'] = isset($_SESSION['stars4']);
    $_SESSION['points3_set']= isset($_SESSION['points3']);
    $_SESSION['rank3_set']  = isset($_SESSION['rank3']);
    $_SESSION['points4_set']= isset($_SESSION['points4']);
    $_SESSION['rank4_set']  = isset($_SESSION['rank4']);

    if (!function_exists('threeFunction')) {
        function threeFunction($conn, $userID, $threeRank, $threePoints) {
            if ($threeRank !== 0 && $threePoints !== 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `3star` (playerID, rank, points, arenaID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 6)";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiii", $userID, $threeRank, $threePoints);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!function_exists('fourFunction')) {
        function fourFunction($conn, $userID, $fourRank, $fourPoints, $fourChamps) {
            if ($fourRank !== 0 && $fourPoints !== 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `4star` (playerID, rank, points, arenaID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 6)";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiii", $userID, $fourRank, $fourPoints);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$_SESSION['name_set']) {
        echo '<form method="post" id="form">';
        echo '<label>Player Username: <input type="text" name="username" required /></label>';
        echo '<label>I participated in the arena for 3-star Winter Soldier: <input type="checkbox" name="tstar" /></label>';
        echo '<label>I participated in the arena for 4-star Winter Soldier: <input type="checkbox" name="fstar" /></label>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<input type="submit" />';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        if ($_SESSION['stars3_set'] && !$_SESSION['points3_set']) {
            echo '<form method="post" id="form">';
            echo '<h3>3* Winter Soldier Arena</h3>';
            echo '<label>How many <span class="bold">points</span> did you gain in the arena?<br />&#9;<input type="number" name="tpoints" required /></label>';
            echo '<label>What did you <span class="bold">rank</span> with the aforementioned points?<br />&#9;<input type="number" name="trank" required /></label>';
            // echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" /><input type="checkbox" name="tstar" checked style="display:none" />';
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<input type="submit" />';
            echo '</form>';
        } else if ($_SESSION['stars4_set'] && !$_SESSION['points4_set']) {
            echo '<form method="post" id="form">';
            echo '<h3>4* Winter Soldier Arena</h3>';
            echo '<label>How many <span class="bold">points</span> did you gain in the arena?<br />&#9;<input type="number" name="tpoints" required /></label>';
            echo '<label>What did you <span class="bold">rank</span> with the aforementioned points?<br />&#9;<input type="number" name="trank" required /></label>';
            // echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" /><input type="checkbox" name="fstar" checked style="display:none" />';
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<input type="submit" />';
            echo '</form>';
        } else {
            $server = 'server';
            $database = 'database';
            $user = 'user';
            $pass = 'password';

            $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);

            if (!$conn) {
                die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql = "SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = '" . $_SESSION['name'] . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $userID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['id'];

                threeFunction($conn, $userID, $_SESSION['rank3'], $_SESSION['points3']);
                fourFunction($conn, $userID, $_SESSION['rank4'], $_SESSION['points4']);
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('$username')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    $userID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

                    threeFunction($conn, $userID, $_SESSION['rank3'], $_SESSION['points3']);
                    fourFunction($conn, $userID, $_SESSION['rank4'], $_SESSION['points4']);
                }
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo "<p>Thank you, " . $_SESSION['name'] . ", for helping gather information for a more comprehensive feel as to what goes on behind the curtains.</p>";

        }
    }
[/insert_php]
</div>
```

Just so it's easier to spot, line 64 is

```
} else if ($_SESSION['stars4_set'] && !$_SESSION['points4_set']) {
```

Can someone please tell me why it will not go into that if-statement and instead start again?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the 2nd form, there is no $_POST['username'] so this line re-sets $_SESSION['name'] to NULL / FALSE:

```
$_SESSION['name']   = $_POST['username'];
```

Then, this line sets $_SESSION['name_set'] to FALSE

```
$_SESSION['name_set']   = isset($_SESSION['name']);
```

Which is why you end up back at the first form. You just need an IF statement around those $_POST variables:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) $_SESSION['name'];
```

That will stop $_SESSION['name'] being overwritten.

Comment: Btw the GravityForms plugin has conditional logic and an API - I use it for all custom forms, and I haven't needed to custom code one yet :)

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks! I'll have a look at GravityForms as well.

Comment: What GravityForms plugin is it? There are quite a few.

Comment: http://www.gravityforms.com/purchase-gravity-forms/ - unfortunately not free, but one of the most useful plugins I've ever purchased